# plot the PSD of an image vs. x/y axis

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

a research professor asked me to generate 2d-spatial spectrum density plots for a couple of videos. I have two problems:

1. How can I plot the PSD vs. x,y axis?
2. I know how to generate PSD for images, but uncertain how to do the same on videos. I thought about getting PSDs for every frame in the video and take the average, but I am having difficulties implementing it in python.

Below is the code I have

```
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
img = cv2.imread(curr_dir+'/test.jpg',0)
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
mag = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(mag,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

This generates something like this:

[image]

I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to generate a 2D spacial spectral density plot for every frame in the video, making a sort of cube of PSDs over time? Or a 1-D PSD per frame, making a waterfall plot where one axis is your PSD and the other axis is time?

Comment: @Engineero Hi, I am trying to generate a spatial spectral density plot for videos (I know it sounds weird but that's what was asked of me). I want to plot the x(along wind) and y(across wind) components of the PSD vs. frequency.

Answer (score 3):

Since you show two 1d spectra, it would seem that you are looking for something like the following.

We read in the image, Fourier transform along one axis, and then sum the power in each bin, along the other axis.  Since the input is real valued, we use rfft() so what we do not have to shift the spectrum, and we use rfftreq() to calculate the frequency for each bin.  We graph the result omitting the sometimes large signal in the 0 frequency bin (which corresponds to baseline) so that the useful part of the spectrum appears on a convenient scale.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cv2
import os
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

curr_dir = os.getcwd()
img = cv2.imread(curr_dir+'/temp.png',0)
print( img.shape )

# Fourier Transform along the first axis

# Round up the size along this axis to an even number
n = int( math.ceil(img.shape[0] / 2.) * 2 )

# We use rfft since we are processing real values
a = np.fft.rfft(img,n, axis=0)

# Sum power along the second axis
a = a.real*a.real + a.imag*a.imag
a = a.sum(axis=1)/a.shape[1]

# Generate a list of frequencies
f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

# Graph it
plt.plot(f[1:],a[1:], label = 'sum of amplitudes over y vs f_x')

# Fourier Transform along the second axis

# Same steps as above
n = int( math.ceil(img.shape[1] / 2.) * 2 )

a = np.fft.rfft(img,n,axis=1)

a = a.real*a.real + a.imag*a.imag
a = a.sum(axis=0)/a.shape[0]

f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

plt.plot(f[1:],a[1:],  label ='sum of amplitudes over x vs f_y')

plt.ylabel( 'amplitude' )
plt.xlabel( 'frequency' )
plt.yscale( 'log' )

plt.legend()

plt.savefig( 'test_rfft.png' )
#plt.show()
```

Applying this to the photograph posted in your question, produces the following result,

[image]